# How to create in-cell drop down that will create & sync new Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I'm wondering how to do the following in Google Sheets...

1. Create an in-cell drop-down so that the values that I select will

   - create a new sheet for each row when there's a new value selected for the in-cell drop-down, and then
   - sync the rows with the in-cell drop-down selected values in the newly created sheets
2. Create an in-cell drop-down that will

   - create new tabbed sheets for each row when there's a new value selected for the in-cell drop-down, and then
   - sync the rows with the in-cell drop-down selected values in the newly created tabbed sheets

Comment: Welcome. Items 1 and 2 above are identical, but don't worry about that. What you describe is possible using a script, but I'd like to know what you mean by "there's a new value selected" - is it, perhaps, that, of all the possible values for the dropdown, this is the first time that a value has been selected? Have you written any code at all, or researched/found similar topics?

Comment: Sorry - I just realized I overlooked your questions, which I've partly answered below. To answer & clarify your remaining questions: I'd like to set up the dropdown values both for CATEGORIES _and_ SUBCATEGORIES -- and also have the ability to add to them as I go. Possible? Yes, I've researched this but haven't found any solutions-only more questions. I'm afraid I'm a novice at code. BTW, there's a small difference between examples 1 & 2 (above): (1) aims to create a discrete, stand-alone sheet;  (2)  _tabbed_ sheets within one sheet doc. Quickly...should I copy & apply your code? If so, how?

Comment: "_I'm afraid I'm a novice at code._" Everyone is a novice at the outset, but it is not hard and there are many sources of tutorials available to develop skills. "BTW, there's a small difference..." - my apologies; possibly this is a result of misinterpretation - a "spreadsheet" is a file that can contain one or more "sheets". A "sheet" is often colloquially known as/called a "tab". I suggest that you edit your question so that there is no confusion about the specific outcome that you want to achieve in each case. Scripting of either can be done relatively easily.

Comment: "_Everyone is a novice at the outset, but it is not hard and there are many sources of tutorials available to develop skills._" I hear you, but I'm severely dyslexic, so I'm not well-equipped to work on code, alas - and it hasn't been for lack of trying! "_I suggest that you edit your question so that there is no confusion about the specific outcome that you want to achieve in each case._" Got it. So, I'd like the CATEGORY value to create a sheet, and the SUBCATEGORY value to create a tab within that sheet. Happy to provide more info that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

On entering a dropdown value in a column, if this is the first use of that dropdown value, then you want to create a sheet with the name of the dropdown value. If it isn't the first use, then there is no action (other than to populate the dropdown).

This requires a combination of factors:detecting the dropdown, ensuring it is in the right sheet, column and row, determining whether the value has been used before and, if not, to create the new sheet. There are probably many ways that this might be done; consider the following just one example.

In this example, the relevant sheet to watch is "Sheet1", and the relevant column is "Column A". There is one header row, and there are dropdown cells in the rows below the header row.

The logic flow is:

- use a simple [onEdit(e) trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedite) to detect data entry.
- use [Event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) to determine the edited column, row, sheet name and value.
- use other variables to manage the number of header rows, and the relevant column to watch.
- create an `IF` statement to confirm that the edit was in the relevant sheet, column and row, then

  - get the range and values in Column A - include row 1 so that `setValues()` will always apply
  - flatten the resulting 2D array to 1D using the Javascript [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method
  - find the first and last occurence of the dropdown value in the range using Javascript [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf)
  - if the first and last values are the same, then this must be the first and only use of the dropdown value, so create a new sheet [insertSheet(sheetName)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertsheetsheetname) where "sheetname" is the dropdown value.

---

```
function onEdit(e){

  //so5842003001

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheetname = "Sheet1";
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);

  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));//DEBUG

  var eColumn = e.range.getColumn();
  var eRow = e.range.getRow();
  var eSheet = e.source.getSheetName();
  var eValue = e.value;
  var headerrow = 1; // number of header rows
  var column = 1; // the data validation is in Column A
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: column = "+eColumn+", sheet = "+eSheet+", Row = "+eRow+", header = "+headerrow);

  if (sheetname === eSheet && eColumn === column && eRow > headerrow){
    // column. row, and sheet are OK
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: running the if");

    //get the last row
    var rows = sheet.getLastRow();
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: last row = "+rows);

    //define the range
    var columnRange = sheet.getRange(1, column, rows);
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: range = "+columnRange.getA1Notation());

    // get the values
    var columnvalue = columnRange.getValues();
    // Logger.log(columnvalue); // DEBUG

    // flatten the 2D array to 1D
    var  column1D= columnvalue.map(function(d){return d[0];});//[[d],[d],[d]]=>[d,d,d]
    // Logger.log(column1D);// DEBUG

    // get the first time this value appears in the range
    var result =  column1D.indexOf(eValue);
    // get the last time this value appears in the range
    var lastresult = column1D.lastIndexOf(eValue);
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: result = "+result+", lastresult = "+lastresult)

    // if the first time equals the last time, then this must be the first time it has appeared
    // so insert the sheet
    if (result === lastresult){
      //Logger.log("first use of this value"); // DEBUG

      // insert the sheet named for the cell
      ss.insertSheet(eValue);
    }
  }
  else {
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: running the else");
  }
}
```

---

**Screenshot of answer layout**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This is incredible. Thank you so much! Quick question: Would it be possible to add values to the in-cell dropdown as I go OR do they have to be predefined for this set up to work? 

Also,  I've filled it with some data and changed some of the columns & rows.  Here's how it looks now: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lWpdoFGOvzB_a_JewlGmGPUkWUY8GPnEaEhKdFM7lig/edit#gid=0

So, instead of wholly depending on the "AGENCY / SUBAGENCY" column, what about making Row 1 (columns A - G) where the main AGENCY in-cell drop down is located, and then column C will just be for SUBAGENCY.

Comment: Quickly...just to clarify my earlier questions (should I copy & apply your code? If so, how?), I'm wondering if either of us ought to first amend the code, based on what you produced -- and then what I subsequently provided in terms of additional answers, and then a sample of the template itself. Thank you so much again for all of your tremendous help. I'm very grateful.

Comment: The code looks at "selected" values in dropdowns in a given column (I've added a screenshot to demonstrate); add any number of extra values to the validation criteria. Your linked spreadsheet has no dropdowns - decide what you want then look for a solution. "_should I copy & apply your code?_"  I would be surprised if the answer matched your spreadsheet, so I'd expect the code to be modified. "_If so, how?_" - this is up to you because you will modify/install the code. That requires some competence with scripting in Google Sheets on your part.

Comment: First, HUGE thanks again for this! Really appreciate it. Yes, I haven't set up dropdown yet since I figured these kinds of dropdown would need special configuration. I don't mean to ask more of you, esp. since you've been so helpful, but can you provide some guidance about how (where?) to modify/install the code to make it work within my spreadsheet? Happy to seek out additional assistance elsewhere - this is just far beyond my abilities! Many thanks again...

Comment: Also..."_The code looks at "selected" values in dropdowns in a given column (I've added a screenshot to demonstrate); add any number of extra values to the validation criteria._" Sorry - just trying be be sure I understand that I have to start with providing values for a dropdown in order for the script to work, and then I can add them as I go. Have I got that right? Many thanks again...

Comment: I just update the Google Sheet file by including additional data, dropdown, tabs, etc. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lWpdoFGOvzB_a_JewlGmGPUkWUY8GPnEaEhKdFM7lig/edit#gid=0

...and I created another Sheets file to clarify what I'm seeking as far as how the selected dropdown values create standalone sheets (for AGENCY), and tabbed sheets (for SUBAGENCY).
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZvYi2DSUXa24DfrQWeI8dP1h_PQ6N2dj1hxfFFxpePw/edit#gid=0
I hope that this will create less work for you, & make it easier for me to determine how to modify/install the code you created. Thanks!

Comment: I'll edit the question as you outlined-please check my changes; and also look creating the spreadsheet and/or sheet/tab. Are Columns A and B interdependent; is the choice of values in column B dependant on the selection in Column A? 2) You use lists for validation, OK but ranges would be MUCH easier to manage. 3) Please watch [Google Sheets Drop Down List - Data Validation Tutorial, Dynamic Lists from Ranges](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VEJMeYroDTM) (10 minutes) by www.chicagocomputerclasses.com. It's a guide to simplifying dropdown lists. Their stuff is OK.